# How to make a setCategory while using Grouped category plugin in highchart?

Tags: highcharts

```
//Normal way of setting category
this.xAxis[0].setCategories(["category1", "category2"])
```

Is there a similar way to set categories while using a grouped category plugin for the below categories?

```
    categories: [{
        name: "Actual",
        categories: ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]
    }, {
        name: "Forecast",
        categories: ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]
    }, {
        name: "Plan",
        categories: ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]
    }]
```

https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/

Comment: Do you mean set all categoires in all levels or only in the "deep level"?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do :

```
this.xAxis[0].setCategories(
    [{
        name: "Actual",
        categories: ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]
    }, {
        name: "Forecast",
        categories: ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]
    }, {
        name: "Plan",
        categories: ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]
    }]
);
```

Comment: how do i nest it? say this.xAxis.setCategories.setcategories etc? I mean, i would want even the inner array to be set using setCategories

Comment: I don't understand what you want. plug-in `categories` is just an array which elements are normal `categories` attributes.